# For each Word in a File, Find If current Word is Present More than Once

Tags: string, file, go

I'm very new to `Golang` and I'm having some issues on trying to `find` and `print` all the lines in a file which contain a certain same `value`.

My file is structured like the following:

```
index text
index text
     .
     .
     .
index text
```

Where `index` is ALWAYS `6 digits long` and `text` is ALWAYS `16 digits long`.

> I need to `find` and `print` all the lines which contain the same `text` value.

That's what I tried so far:

```
func main() {

    //Array to contain common texts
    found := make([]string, 6)

    r, _ := os.Open("store.txt")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    //Splits in words
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    //Loop over all Words in the file
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        //If the current line is 16 digits long
        if(utf8.RuneCountInString(line) == 16){
           currLine := line
            //Search in the same files all the 16 digits long texts and
            for scanner.Scan(){
                searchLine := scanner.Text()
                //If a same text is found
                if(utf8.RuneCountInString(searchLine) == 16){
                    //Append it to found array
                    if(currLine == searchLine){
                        found = append(found, currLine)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Print found Array
    fmt.Println(found)
    //Close File
    r.Close()
}
```

Then, I would like to use `found` to `print` all the `lines` which match the current `found[i-element]`.

The code above works only for the very first step.
For instance, If in my file, at the very first line it gets `1234567890123456` (e.g. from index 1) then it checks and appends only one time, it does not loop for all the lines (for the remaining n-1 words).

- **How can I fix the first issue?**
- **Do you think adding the duplicate `texts` in an `Array` and then print the matching lines based on it is a bad idea?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is caused because you are using the same stream to read the file and check duplicate so when the inner for reach the bottom of the file finish, then the outer for check if there is something more to scan but it find the EOF and exit.
The easiest way to solve your problem is creating an array where you put all the text that you find for the first time and when the text value are already present just print the duplicate. Something like this:

```
duplicates := make([]string,0)
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    text := line[6:]
    //Do your check
    //if all your control are ok
    if ! contains(duplicates, text) {
        duplicates = append(duplicates, text)
    } else {
        //Print the duplicates
    }
```

And here there is the `contains` implementation

```
func contains(s []string, e string) bool {
    for _, a := range s {
        if a == e {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: How should I do that kind of check?

Comment: Nevermind, it works properly, just need to print `current line`.

Comment: Just a last thing, How am I supposed to print the current duplicate field in a way that I have `currLine, duplicateLIne`, like: `000000 ABABABABABABABAB, 010101 ABABABABABABABAB`?

Comment: Instead of store only the string you can create a struct with the current line and then return the struct when match inside the func contains. Or if you want return all the match inside the array create a temp array in contains, append all the matches and then return the temp array. Hope this can help  you